# Nextjs 13 App Router internalization without sub-routing or domain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, internationalization, next.js13

I am creating web app that can be accessed only when user login.
I use nextjs 13 with App Route (not Pages Route!).

And I am trying to use internalization without having to create sub-route like `/en` or domain like `mywebsite.lang` or `lang.website`. I would like to fetch user data from database of his preferred language and apply it on the whole app. Is it possible?
I read on nextjs doc about i18n but it tells only about using sub-routing or domain. And other blogs or videos available I can find online only demonstrating either sub-route/domain or nextjs using Pages Route.

I have tried this 2 different blogs instruction. But unfortunately it uses Pages Route not App Route, so I can't implement it to my app that uses App Route.
https://hackernoon.com/implementing-i18n-in-nextjs-a-guide-to-non-route-based-localization 
https://iamsannyrai.medium.com/i18n-in-next-js-without-sub-path-or-domain-routing-2443c1a349c6 
When I implement instruction from the blogs above, my codes belows in `src/app/layout.tsx`, it gets error belows.

```
// src/app/layout.tsx
"use client";

import { appWithI18Next, useSyncLanguage } from "ni18n";

import { ni18nConfig } from "../../ni18n.config.js";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const locale =
    typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage.getItem("MY_LANGUAGE");

  useSyncLanguage(locale || "en");

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default appWithI18Next(MyApp, ni18nConfig);
```

```
// ni18n.config.js


export const ni18nConfig = {
  supportedLngs: ["en", "id"],
  ns: ["sign-up"],
};
```

error

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'locale')

Call Stack
WithI18Next
node_modules/ni18n/dist/esm/app-with-i18next/app-with-i18next.js (71:0)
renderWithHooks
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (10697:0)
updateFunctionComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (15180:0)
mountLazyComponent
node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (15620:0)
...
```

---

update: still not working

```
/// src/pages/_app.tsx

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { I18nextProvider } from "react-i18next";
import { serverSideTranslations } from "next-i18next/serverSideTranslations";

import i18n from "../../i18n";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(pageProps.locale);

  useEffect(() => {
    // update locale on client
    setLocale(window.localStorage.getItem("locale"));
  }, []);

  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // fetch user locale from DB
  const locale = "en";

  return {
    props: {
      ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale)),
      locale,
    },
  };
}
```

```
// i18n.js
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import i18n from "i18next";

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  lng: "en",
  fallbackLng: "en",
});

export default i18n;
```

```
// src/app/coba/page.tsx

"use client";

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

function Coba() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return <div>content Coba: {t("lang")}</div>;
}

export default Coba;
```

```
// public/locales/en/sign-up.json

{
  "lang": "language"
}
```

When I go to url `/coba` on browser, the result is

```
content Coba: lang
```

that should be "content Coba: language"

Answer (score 1):

You should take a different path Because there is a server components too
First Download the following packages with this command:

```
npm install @formatjs/intl-localematcher negotiator next-int && npm install -D @types/negotiator server-only
```

I will separate the config Because it will be easier to change it later

i18n.config.ts

```js
export const i18n = {
  defaultLocale: "en",
  locales: ["en", "de"], /* All locales you have */
} as const

export type Locale = (typeof i18n)["locales"][number]
```

Then we will make the configuration for the server:

dictionary.ts

```js
import "server-only"

import type { Locale } from "@/config/i18n.config"

const dictionaries = {
  "en": () => import("pathToJsonFile/en.json").then((module) => module.default),
  "de": () => import("pathToJsonFile/de.json").then((module) => module.default),
}

/* We will use getDictionary function for server components*/
export const getDictionary = async (locale: Locale) => dictionaries[locale]()
```

We need to create a function to detect locale

```js
import { NextRequest } from "next/server"
import { match as matchLocale } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher"
import Negotiator from "negotiator"
import { i18n } from "pathToConfig/i18n.config"

function getLocale(request: NextRequest): string | undefined {
  const languageCookie = request.cookies.get("NEXT_LOCALE")?.value
  if (languageCookie) {
    return languageCookie
  }
  const negotiatorHeaders: Record<string, string> = {}
  request.headers.forEach((value, key) => (negotiatorHeaders[key] = value))

  // @ts-ignore locales are readonly
  const locales: string[] = i18n.locales
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers: negotiatorHeaders }).languages()

  const locale = matchLocale(languages, locales, i18n.defaultLocale)
  return locale
}
```

Then we need middleware:

middleware.ts

```js
import { type NextRequest } from "next/server"
import createIntlMiddleware from "next-intl/middleware"

/* I am creating a new function because if you have more than 1 middleware it will be easier to manage but You can directly use it with default export */
export const MultiLanguageMiddleware = (request: NextRequest) => {
  const defaultLocale =
    getLocale(request) || request.headers.get("x-default-locale") || "en"

  const intlMiddleware = createIntlMiddleware({
    /* @ts-ignore */
    locales: i18n.locales,
    localePrefix: "never", /* we will give "never" value because we don't want domain or prefix based locale. */
    defaultLocale: defaultLocale || "en", 
    localeDetection: false,
  })

  return intlMiddleware(request)
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {

 /* Then you can can create custom logic or directly call here */

return MultiLanguageMiddleware
}

export const config = {
  // Skip all paths that should not be internationalized. This example skips the
  // folders "api", "_next" and all files with an extension (e.g. favicon.ico)
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next|.*\\..*).*)']
};
```

Then we have to define types for server component IntelliSense:

global.d.ts

```js
type Messages = typeof import("pathToYourFile/en.json")
declare interface IntlMessages extends Messages {}
```

Now we need a provider for client components:

providers.tsx

```js
"use client"

import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { NextIntlClientProvider } from "next-intl"

interface ProvidersProps {
  children: React.ReactNode
  lang: string
  messages: any
}

const Providers: FC<ProvidersProps> = ({ children, lang, messages }) => {
  /* We are ensuring we are in client because of avoiding next.js 13 hydration errors */
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true)
  }, [])
  if (!isMounted) return null

  return (
    
      <NextIntlClientProvider locale={lang} messages={messages}>
      {children}
      </NextIntlClientProvider>
    
  )
}

export default Providers
```

before we add our layout file we have to move every route in the app directory to the [lang] folder like this:
[image]

layout.tsx

```
import { i18n, Locale } from "pathToConfig/i18n.config"
import Providers from "pathToProvidersComponent/providers"

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: { lang },
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
  params: { lang: Locale }
}) {
  let messages
  try {
    messages = (await import(`pathToFile/lang.json`)).default
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
/* our fallback locale */
    messages = (await import(`pathToFile/en.json`)).default
  }
  return (
    <html lang={lang}>
      <body>
          <Providers lang={lang} messages={messages}>
           {children}
          </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

client component usage:

```js
"use client"
import { useTranslations } from "next-intl"

const Page = () => {
  const t = useTranslations("yours")


return (
<div>
{t("path.to.message")}
</div>
)

}
```

server component usage:

```js
import { getDictionary } from "filePath/dictionary"
import { Locale } from "pathToI18nConfig/i18n.config"

interface pageProps {
  params: {
    lang: Locale
  }
}

const Page: FC<pageProps> = async ({ params: { lang } }) => {
  const translation = await getDictionary(lang)

return (
<div>
{translation.yours}
</div>
)}
```

Comment: Really nice and deep explination to this issue that im also trying to solve. But there is still that aweful [lang] folder. Could there not be a solution where we can set the culture based on the user setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **next/headers**:
this will read the browser header related to the language and then you can use it as a value without changing the route or using sub-routes.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers#headers

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers'

export default function Page() {
  const headersList = headers()
  const lang = headersList.get('accept-language')
 
  return <div>Lang: {lang}</div>
}
```